# a col("unitePurgeeUniteLegale").equalTo("true").cast(BooleanType) returns true or... null

Tags: java, apache-spark

On Spark `3.0.2` I don't understand the behavior of `equalTo` in a column expression evaluating a condition on a `StringType`, and giving its result in a `BooleanType` column.

I have a `csv` file that list enterprises, and its third column `unitePurgeeUniteLegale` of `StringType` is *true* when an enterprise is too old and closed for so long time that no accurate data accompanies it : it is now purged.

```
siren,statutDiffusionUniteLegale,unitePurgeeUniteLegale,dateCreationUniteLegale,sigleUniteLegale,sexeUniteLegale,prenom1UniteLegale,prenom2UniteLegale,prenom3UniteLegale,prenom4UniteLegale,prenomUsuelUniteLegale,pseudonymeUniteLegale,identifiantAssociationUniteLegale,trancheEffectifsUniteLegale,anneeEffectifsUniteLegale,dateDernierTraitementUniteLegale,nombrePeriodesUniteLegale,categorieEntreprise,anneeCategorieEntreprise,dateDebut,etatAdministratifUniteLegale,nomUniteLegale,nomUsageUniteLegale,denominationUniteLegale,denominationUsuelle1UniteLegale,denominationUsuelle2UniteLegale,denominationUsuelle3UniteLegale,categorieJuridiqueUniteLegale,activitePrincipaleUniteLegale,nomenclatureActivitePrincipaleUniteLegale,nicSiegeUniteLegale,economieSocialeSolidaireUniteLegale,caractereEmployeurUniteLegale
000325175,O,,2000-09-26,,M,THIERRY,,,,THIERRY,,,,,2019-12-13T13:21:28,6,PME,2017,2018-02-07,A,JANOYER,,,,,,1000,32.12Z,NAFRev2,00065,,N
001807254,O,,1972-05-01,,M,JACQUES-LUCIEN,,,,JACQUES-LUCIEN,,,,,2016-07-10T05:00:06,5,,,2014-12-31,C,BRETON,,,,,,1000,85.59A,NAFRev2,00022,,N
005410220,O,true,1954-12-25,,M,GEORGES,,,,GEORGES,,,,,,1,,,1988-03-31,C,WATTEBLED,,,,,,1000,22.02,NAP,00015,,N
005410345,O,true,,,M,MICHEL,,,,MICHEL,,,,,,1,,,1984-12-25,C,DEBRAY,,,,,,1000,79.06,NAP,00010,,N
```

Above, entrerprise of Mr. THIERRY has still accurate data, but Mr. GEORGES one is purged.

I create a `Dataset` from that csv, having this column, with a cast :

```java
entreprises = enterprises.withColumn("purgee", 
   col("unitePurgeeUniteLegale").equalTo("true").cast(BooleanType))
```

Then when I'm using this `Dataset` to retain only **not** purged enterprises...

```java
entreprises = entreprises.where(col("purgee").equalTo(false));
```

...I gather none ! If purged ones have for boolean value *true* in the `purgee` column of `BooleanType`, others have a ***null*** value !

I have a workaround :
Creating my `purgee` column with this statement works :

```java
entreprises = entreprises.withColumn("purgee", 
   when(col("unitePurgeeUniteLegale").equalTo("true"), true).otherwise(false))
```

But what's that story of that strange `col("unitePurgeeUniteLegale").equalTo("true")` or
`col("unitePurgeeUniteLegale").equalTo("true").cast(BooleanType)`
that responds something else than *true* or *false* ? *Apache Spark* who, like *Jimmy Hendrix*, tries the *Ultimate Experience* ?

If it's a normal *Apache Spark* behavior, does *Spark* have an alternative `equalTo` method that works like in all other languages: returning **only** *true* or *false* ?

Comment: that's called `eqNullSafe`

Comment: Thanks ! But what means unsafe for `equalTo` ? How can an equal test of two values return null ? It's very bug prone.

Comment: You can see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-null-semantics.html